# QtDesigner widget events not firing

Tags: python, qt, events, widget, pyside

So I am trying to make a label in PySide Qt which, when resized will run my function, I am making the GUI in QtDesigner.

The problem is if I make the label through QtDesigner and then try to do: `self.window.myLabel.resizeEvent = my_event`

Then nothing gets emitted. however if I make the label manually

```
self.myLabel = QLabel(self.window.parent_widget)
self.myLabel.resizeEvent = my_event
```

then it works fine. Am I using QtDesigner incorrectly?